# Why in Python sometimes from PIL import Image fails and import Image works?

Tags: python

The below piece of code seems to fails for some people while the second one seems to works.

I would like to know why and which would be the best option to choose in order to minimize potential import failures?

```
from PIL import Image # Fails for some ?!
import Image
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"`import Image`" works because PIL makes use of the [site-specific import hooks](http://docs.python.org/library/site.html) to add its install directory into the import path.

```
[me@oldserver]$ cat /usr/lib/python2.4/site-packages/PIL.pth
PIL
```

The only situation I can think of where "`import Image`" works but "`from PIL import Image`" doesn't is if the install directory for PIL is outside of the import path but a `.pth` file exists which points to `/some/install/path/PIL`.

Answer (score 2):

refering [PIL Install](http://www.sandersnewmedia.com/why/2012/04/16/installing-pil-virtualenv-ubuntu-1204-precise-pangolin/)

Step 1 : Install the build dependencies

```
sudo apt-get build-dep python-imaging
```

Step 2 : Symlink the libraries

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/`uname -i`-linux-gnu/libfreetype.so /usr/lib/
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/`uname -i`-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so /usr/lib/
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/`uname -i`-linux-gnu/libz.so /usr/lib/
```

Step 3 : Install

```
pip install PIL
```