# ImportError: No module named 'PIL' in python 3.4

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-3.x

I have such code in the beginning of a file:

```
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageFont
from PIL import ImageDraw
```

And it throws the error:

```
python3 main.pyTraceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from PIL import Image
ImportError: No module named 'PIL'
```

According to many ad vices I should just replace `import PIL` with what I actually have. But is doesn't work as you can see.

It's on Ubuntu 14.04 and Python 3.4.0

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19628673/2915834 sounds like a solution for this.

Comment: `sudo apt-get install python3-pil`: [http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/python3-pil](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/python3-pil).

Comment: @frlan - error: `Picking 'pillow' as source package instead of 'python-imaging'
E: Unable to find a source package for pillow`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863917/importerror-no-module-named-pil) you should be able to do `import Image` instead of `import PIL`.

Comment: Debian-based distros use the pillow fork of PIL, which requires [`from PIL import Image`](http://pillow.readthedocs.org/en/latest/porting-pil-to-pillow.html).